# Tab bar image not showing

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

My code is given bellow:

```
UITabBar *tabBar = (UITabBar *)_tabbBarControllr.tabBar;


UITabBarItem *chatItem = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];

[chatItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ChatDeselect.png"]];
[chatItem setSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Chatselect.png"]];


//tab2
 UITabBarItem *groupItem = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];

[groupItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"GropuChatDeselect.png"]];
[groupItem setSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"GropuChatSelect.png"]];


//tab3
UITabBarItem *settingsItem = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];

[settingsItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SettingsDeselect.png"]];
[settingsItem setSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SettingsSelect.png"]];
```

Image are not showing for selected & deselected state.
Can anybody suggest me?

Comment: Check your image name twice

Comment: and check, if they are copied to bundle during build phase.

Comment: we have checked,all are ok.

Comment: I have checked again & icon size make 30X30, selected images are showing, but normal image are not showing.

Comment: Try initializing your images like this: `[[UIImage imageNamed:@"SettingsDeselect.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]`

Comment: imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal : Its working in ios7. Its available  for ios 7. My app support from ios6.

Comment: Please, add your images from Assets.xassets to `Media Library` (see .storyboard file, <resources> tag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the item to the related view controller like this - assuming your can get each one of the related view controllers :

```
UITabBarItem *chatItem = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];

[chatItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ChatDeselect.png"]];
[chatItem setSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Chatselect.png"]];

// Setting here, admitting that you have created this controller before
yourViewController.tabBarItem = chatItem;
```

And then, assign all of theses ViewControllers to your UITabBarController this way, creating an array with them :

```
yourTabBarController.viewControllers = @[yourViewCtrl1, yourViewCtrl2, yourViewCtrl3];
```